# Using both p{} and r/l/c in tabularize

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{12cm}}
\textbf{Socialism in One Country}:&  Bolshevik foreign policy transformed from expansion and advancement to internal consolidation and defence, from which emerged Stalin's Socialism in One Country\\
\textbf{Permanent Revolution}: & Foreign policy in inter-war based on survival of revolution, thus permanent world revolution. But this was not likely to happen\\
\textbf{Comintern}:& Created a network of \textbf{spies}, attempting to influence international labor organizations. Supported unsuccessful revolts in Hungary and Germany. Active in Britain and America too, and the Communist Party of the USA was created.\\
\textbf{Gregory Chicherin}:& First \textbf{Commissar for Foreign Affairs}. After Russo-Polish War, Treaty of Riga, he equally divided Belarus and Ukraine with Poland, and return Polish treasures. Thus Unpopular, but later established trade arrangements with Britain, France and Italy, who later diplomatically recognized Russia. This was short-lived wegen den Comintern's involvement im Britania. Was successful in Germany with rearmament program.\\
\end{tabular}
```

Is it possible to make the first column centered to the right? What I want is `\begin{tabular}{r l}` but I ALSO want `\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{12cm}}`. Is this possible?

EDIT 16/9/21 **is it also possible to have the table span across multiple pages, which can be done with `\begin{longtable}`. So is there a solution that encompasses all three features?**

Comment: Please clarify what you maen by "centered to the right". Do you maybe mean "flushright", aka "ragged-left"?

Comment: yes thats what i meant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\bfseries\raggedleft}p{2.75cm} X @{}}
Socialism in One Country
& Bolshevik foreign policy transformed from expansion and advancement to internal consolidation and defence, from which emerged Stalin's Socialism in One Country\\
Permanent Revolution 
& Foreign policy in inter-war based on survival of revolution, thus permanent world revolution. But this was not likely to happen\\
Comintern 
& Created a network of \textbf{spies}, attempting to influence international labor organizations. Supported unsuccessful revolts in Hungary and Germany. Active in Britain and America too, and the Communist Party of the USA was created.\\
Gregory Chicherin 
& First \textbf{Commissar for Foreign Affairs}. After Russo-Polish War, Treaty of Riga, he equally divided Belarus and Ukraine with Poland, and return Polish treasures. Thus Unpopular, but later established trade arrangements with Britain, France and Italy, who later diplomatically recognized Russia. This was short-lived wegen den Comintern's involvement im Britania. Was successful in Germany with rearmament program.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry but there is a further feature I wanted and I might make a new post if it's not appropriate for me to ask here, but is it possible to use `\begin{longtable}` with this as well? Essentially I ALSO want it to be able to go multiple pages

Comment: what is an X column type?

Comment: and what is the purpose of the `>`?

Comment: @user71207 - The `tabularx` package provides an environment called `tabularx` and a column type called `X`. To learn more about this column type, may I suggest you peruse the user guide of the `tabularx` package? (To open the user guide in a pdf browser, open a command window and type `texdoc tabularx`.) The syntax of the `>{...}` "column prefixes" is described in the user guide of the `array` package. To obtain an answer to your first question, please post a new query.

Answer (score 6):

An easy solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{Q[r,3cm]Q[l,12cm]}
  \textbf{Socialism in One Country}:&  Bolshevik foreign policy transformed from expansion and advancement to internal consolidation and defence, from which emerged Stalin's Socialism in One Country\\
  \textbf{Permanent Revolution}: & Foreign policy in inter-war based on survival of revolution, thus permanent world revolution. But this was not likely to happen\\
  \textbf{Comintern}:& Created a network of \textbf{spies}, attempting to influence international labor organizations. Supported unsuccessful revolts in Hungary and Germany. Active in Britain and America too, and the Communist Party of the USA was created.\\
  \textbf{Gregory Chicherin}:& First \textbf{Commissar for Foreign Affairs}. After Russo-Polish War, Treaty of Riga, he equally divided Belarus and Ukraine with Poland, and return Polish treasures. Thus Unpopular, but later established trade arrangements with Britain, France and Italy, who later diplomatically recognized Russia. This was short-lived wegen den Comintern's involvement im Britania. Was successful in Germany with rearmament program.\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the Q stand for? (in place of p{})

Comment: See the manual: Q stands for a primitive column, p{2cm} is the same as Q[t,2cm] in tabularray.

Comment: But t is the default vertical alignment, so we can omit it.

Comment: To get a long table, replace tblr with longtblr.

Comment: thanks for the replies. Also, your code doesn't work for me and I don't know why/ I suspect its because I am using TexShop LaTeX and the package inst available? It says LaTeX error, tdlr environment undefined.

Comment: Update your TeXLive or MikTeX first.

Answer (score 4):

A small variant of @L.J.R answer:

- text in the first column has boldface
- for the second column is used `X` column type, text in it is justified (`X[j]`)
- table nicely fit in text area

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{@{} Q[r,3cm,font=\bfseries]X[j] @{}}
Socialism in One Country:
    &  Bolshevik foreign policy transformed from expansion and advancement to internal consolidation and defence, from which emerged Stalin's Socialism in One Country\\
Permanent Revolution: 
    & Foreign policy in inter-war based on survival of revolution, thus permanent world revolution. But this was not likely to happen\\
Comintern:
    & Created a network of \textbf{spies}, attempting to influence international labor organizations. Supported unsuccessful revolts in Hungary and Germany. Active in Britain and America too, and the Communist Party of the USA was created.\\
Gregory Chicherin:
    & First \textbf{Commissar for Foreign Affairs}. After Russo-Polish War, Treaty of Riga, he equally divided Belarus and Ukraine with Poland, and return Polish treasures. Thus Unpopular, but later established trade arrangements with Britain, France and Italy, who later diplomatically recognized Russia. This was short-lived wegen den Comintern's involvement im Britannia. Was successful in Germany with rearmament program.
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area border)

*Note*: in MWE is considered the `tabularray` version 2021N.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}p[r]{3cm}p[l]{12cm}}
  Socialism in One Country:&  Bolshevik foreign policy transformed from expansion and advancement to internal consolidation and defence, from which emerged Stalin's Socialism in One Country\\
  Permanent Revolution: & Foreign policy in inter-war based on survival of revolution, thus permanent world revolution. But this was not likely to happen\\
  Comintern:& Created a network of \textbf{spies}, attempting to influence international labor organizations. Supported unsuccessful revolts in Hungary and Germany. Active in Britain and America too, and the Communist Party of the USA was created.\\
  Gregory Chicherin:& First \textbf{Commissar for Foreign Affairs}. After Russo-Polish War, Treaty of Riga, he equally divided Belarus and Ukraine with Poland, and return Polish treasures. Thus Unpopular, but later established trade arrangements with Britain, France and Italy, who later diplomatically recognized Russia. This was short-lived wegen den Comintern's involvement im Britania. Was successful in Germany with rearmament program.\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

For future readers of my question, to allow for a long table as well, the package `xltabular` worked nicely for me. Simply replacing all `tabularx` from Mico's answer to `xltabular` allowed me to have all three features: ragged left, a fixed column width and a long table